# Proper way to clean up views after calling presentViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, presentmodalviewcontroller

I got an app with a logoff button on all of my pages. When the logoff button gets pressed i want my app to go to my login screen. I do this by calling the following in my IBAction for the logoff button:

```
loginScreen = [[GP_MobilViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GP_MobilViewController" bundle:nil];
[currentView presentViewController:loginScreen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now my problem is i don't know how to remove all of the previous created screens. Because form what i can tell, presentViewController won't remove anything for me, so i have to do this cleanup myself?

PS. I'm not using a UINavigationController. So popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES, Won't work for me. I need another solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think it's time to regret for not using UINavigationController. How do you keep all your previous view controllers if not in navigation controller's stack?

Comment: I would reconsider your app's architecture... `presentViewController` shows a modal viewcontroller. Modal VC's require a parent VC. So you can't just pop that one...

Comment: I already am, but i didn't start this project so i would have to rewrite a hell of a lot code to use it. I got a total of 40 viewControllers. So if i some how could loop through all of the created views and remove them. But i have no idea where to start.

Comment: why you not using navigation controller

Comment: Sadly it wasn't my choice not to use navigationControllers because i got handed over this 3 years old project, so now i'm trying to optimize it as much as possible, which means at some point i would use navigationcontrollers. But atm my priorities are to fix some of the broken features there is in the app.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.view.window.rootViewController = self;
```

or in the completion block,

```
loginScreen = [[GP_MobilViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GP_MobilViewController" bundle:nil];
[currentView presentViewController:loginScreen animated:YES completion:^{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController =loginScreen;
}];
```

or in your `loginViewControllers-viewDidAppear` also you can set it as rootViewController to window.
This makes all the viewControllers to be freed.

Comment: yes , you can. add dealloc method (write NSLog in it) in other view controller which need to be freed. when you present loginController,dealloc will be called in all other viewcontrollers except in loginController.

Comment: hmm I've tried your suggestion for completion block. But it only removes the currentView and not the view between loginView and currentView. ETC if i got View A/B/C/D and A=login D=currentView, it removes D and go to A, B and C is not getting dealloc'ed

Comment: the only reason why viewcontrollers are not deallocated are because their retain count is not zero."Say A presents B ,B presents C and window.rootViewController=A ". C is not freed because it has reference from B, B is not removed because has reference from A, A is referenced from window's rootViewController property. So, when you change window.rootVC to D, then A has no strong reference, hence A will be removed.As A is removed, B has no strong reference,so now B will be removed.similarly C. this is the logic that happens with ARC. Make sure B,C are not referenced from other places.Debug......